# Array Can't Initialised Properly it missing 4 and 8 why in the following code?

Tags: java, arrays

In the following code  the array is not properly initialized. the statement in 'else' part a[ro][co]=i, inside the for(int i:x) loop does not worked.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Array {

    int row,col;
    int[][] a;
    Array(int r, int c) { // constructor
        this.row = r;
        this.col = c;
        this.a = new int[r][c];
    }

    void inItems(int... x) { // initialize the array
        int ro = 0;
        int co = 0;
        int t;
        for (int i : x)  {
            if (ro < this.row && co < this.col) {
                a[ro][co] = i; // Works
                co++;
            }
            else {
                co = 0;
                ro++;
                a[ro][co] = i; // Does not work this line
            }
        }
    }

    void outItems() {
        for (int r = 0; r < this.row; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < this.col; c++) {
                System.out.print(this.a[r][c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Array n = new Array(3, 3);
        n.inItems(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
        n.outItems();
    }
}
```

Why are the elements 4 and 8 skipped? I executed but it always prints

```
1 2 3
5 6 7
9 0 0
```

Please, help me.

Comment: ***part inside the for(int i:x) loop does not worked***... what does that mean? why is not working

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 3):

They are not skipped, they are overwritten, since you forgot to increment `co` in the else clause.

```
        if (ro < this.row && co < this.col) {
            a[ro][co] = i;
            co++;
        } else {
            co = 0;
            ro++;
            a[ro][co] = i;
            co++; // you are missing this, so 2 numbers are written to a[1][0] and a[2][0]
        }
```